# Excel-matching row order in two spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large set of data in an Excel spreadsheet (several hundred rows) that is on a shared folder, so other people have access to the file.  A coworker is performing statistics on the data using another program (I don't know what they are using) and has somehow linked the Excel file and their stats file.  I have added several columns of new data, but when I sent it to the other user, they said it would not work with their other program because the rows were not in the same order.  I cannot figure out how their version of the file was sorted, so I cannot re-sort my rows to match their order and then insert the new columns of data into their sheet.  Is there any way you can tell Excel to sort one spreadsheet to match the order of another spreadsheet?  I'm hoping to avoid having to manually reorder the few hundred rows to match.

Example:
Current order

- ID   Age Blood type
- 1    25  A-
- 2    30  A-
- 3    55  AB+

Desired Order

- ID   Age Blood type
- 1    25  A-
- 3    55  AB+
- 2    30  A-

Comment: It would seem the co-worker relying upon row location staying the same is your problem. If there is no way around that, how about giving yourself a sorting column for each of the possible layouts?

Comment: I just used your idea, and it worked great.  I was able to add a sequential column to the co-worker's spreadsheet, then sort his the same as my copy, add his label to mine, then reorder to match.  If you want to repost as an answer, I can mark it as accepted.  Thanks!!

Comment: glad it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

It would seem the co-worker relying upon row location staying the same is your problem. If there is no way around that, give yourself an adjacent sorting column for each of the possible sorting preferences. Sequential numbers for each situation allow you to sort for whatever you need.